# VBA Collection not adding numeric items

Tags: vba, collections

I am trying to use Collection to retrieve unique items in a range.

The code works well with string items. But if I replace the string with numeric items, using the same code, the collection is empty after run. No items added. No errors found.
Would very much appreciate any help!!!

```
Sub unique_val()
Dim unique As New Collection
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Integer

'Updating collection items
On Error Resume Next  'in order to ignore key repeating
For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("a1:c9")
    unique.Add cell.Value, cell.Value
Next
On Error GoTo 0

'Print collection items to sheet
For i = 1 To unique.Count
    Cells(i, 5) = unique(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Example of data that the code works on:

[image]

Data that code doesnt work:

[image]

Comment: If you comment out your "On Error Resume Next" line, then you'll see why it's failing.  The Collection "key" must be a string value.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.collection.add?view=net-5.0.  Thus, how will you set the key value as a string (when the cell value contains a number)?  (By the way, simply using "On Error Resume Next" is not a great way to deal with duplicates in the collection.  It's only an extra line of code (using Collection.Contains) to determine if a particular key exists in the collection already

Comment: @Craig VBA Collection's don't have a Contains method so the On Error approach is appropriate.

Comment: @Craig: Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BrianMStafford - oh, you're right.  My bad on the "Collection.Contains".  In theory, then, a better approach would be to check for the specific error about an existing key, but not ignore any other error that occurs (otherwise, the issue that Kinsley encountered)

Comment: Try using a `String` key, e.g. `unique.Add cell.Value, Key:=CStr(cell.Value)`